# subversion 1.9 in raspberry pi, contains invalid filesystem format option 'addressing physical'

Tags: svn, raspberry-pi

I've got an svn repository created with VisualSVN, and now I want to transfer it to raspberry pi. But I got an error saying it contains invalid filesystem format option 'addressing physical'

After some googling, I know it has something to do with the new fs format in subversion 1.9, so I tried to upgrade the svn in raspberry pi, but I couldn't. It is still 1.7.5 .....

So does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

I think either I upgrade my pi system or downgrade the repo.
I failed the first one, and not sure how to do the 2nd way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Either upgrade SVN on Raspberry Pi to version 1.9

or create a new repository with old format:

```sh
v=1.7 # old svn version

a=svnrepo # repo for new svn
b=svnrepo-svn$v # repo for old svn

svnadmin info $a | grep Compat
# Compatible With Version: 1.10.0

svnadmin create $b --compatible-version $v

svnadmin dump $a | svnadmin load -q $b

svnadmin info $b | grep Compat
# Compatible With Version: 1.7.0
```

Comment: I tried to upgrade svn on Raspberry Pi, but ...I just couldn't get the latest version...